# How to get the input field values from table present inside Angular reactive form

Tags: arrays, angular, html-table, angular-reactive-forms

I need to get all input values which are present inside the table rows and this table is also present inside one reactive form. I am explaining my code below.

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm" (ngSubmit)="saveProduct($event)" novalidate>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>Product Name</mat-label>
   <input matInput placeholder="Product Name" aria-label="Product Name" formControlName="ProductName" maxlength="70" required>
</mat-form-field>
<div class="section" *ngIf="productForm.get('ProductType').value == 'C' && isConfigSection==1">
   <div class="help-content">
      <h5>Configurables</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="form-content">
      <div class='col-sm-12' style="max-width: 100%;">
         <div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
            <div class="table-wrap">
               <table class="main-table">
                  <tbody *ngIf="ColumnNames.length > 1">
                     <tr *ngFor="let opt of ConfigArr; let i = index;">
                        <td class="sticky-col first-col">
                           {{opt.attrName1}}({{opt.attr1}})
                        </td>
                        <td class="sticky-col second-col">
                           {{opt.attrName2}}({{opt.attr2}})
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add MRP" aria-label="MRP" [(ngModel)]="opt.MRP">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add BaseUnitPrice" aria-label="BaseUnitPrice" [(ngModel)]="opt.BaseUnitPrice">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add DiscountValue" aria-label="DiscountValue" [(ngModel)]="opt.DiscountValue">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <input class="form-control" class="form-control" matInput placeholder="MinBuyQty" aria-label="MinBuyQty" [(ngModel)]="opt.MinBuyQty">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add MinimumPrice" aria-label="MinimumPrice" [(ngModel)]="opt.MinimumPrice">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add TaxPercentage" aria-label="TaxPercentage" [(ngModel)]="opt.TaxPercentage">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add TaxAmount" aria-label="TaxAmount" [(ngModel)]="opt.TaxAmount">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add DiscountPrice" aria-label="DiscountPrice" [(ngModel)]="opt.DiscountPrice">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add MaxBuyQty" aria-label="MaxBuyQty" [(ngModel)]="opt.MaxBuyQty">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add MaximumPrice" aria-label="MaximumPrice" [(ngModel)]="opt.MaximumPrice">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" type="button" (click)="addImage($event, AddImages,i)">
                           Add Image<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                           </button>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

My typescript code is given below.

```
for(let i=0; i< res['data']['Attributes'][this.ColumnNames[0]].length;i++){
   for(let j=0;j< res['data']['Attributes'][this.ColumnNames[1]].length;j++){
       let data = {
                  'attr1':res['data']['Attributes'][this.ColumnNames[0]][i],
                  'attrName1':attrName1,
                  'attr2': res['data']['Attributes'][this.ColumnNames[1]][j],
                  'attrName2': attrName2,
                  "MRP": '',
                  "BaseUnitPrice":'',
                  "DiscountValue": '',
                  "MinBuyQty":'',
                  "MinimumPrice":'',
                  "TaxPercentage":'',
                  "TaxAmount":'',
                  "DiscountPrice":'',
                  "MaxBuyQty":'',
                  "MaximumPrice":''
                }
                this.ConfigArr.push(data);
   }
```

Here I am preparing the array for the table. In this table I have some input fields, I need when thr foem will submit I should get those input values for each row inside that same array. I am using `[(ngModel)]` here but its not working inside the Angular reactive form. I need to fetch those user input values of each row in that table while user will do the form submit.

Comment: this.productForm.value, tried this?

Comment: you say "I am using [(ngModel)] here but its not working inside the Angular reactive form", why do you not use FormArray?. NOTE: if you want to use a [(ngModel)] inside a reactive forms you need use `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"` but in your case, please use a FormArray, has no sense use ngModel to control an array of objects inside a reactive Form

Answer (score 0):

```
` ngOnInit() {
    this.survey = new FormGroup({
      surveyName: new FormControl(''),
      logoUrl: new FormControl(''),
      headerUrl: new FormControl(''),
      headerColor: new FormControl(''),
      footerUrl: new FormControl(''),
      footerColor: new FormControl(''),
      sections: new FormArray([
        this.initSection(),
      ]),
    });
  }

  initSection() {
    return new FormGroup({
      sectionTitle: new FormControl(''),
      sectionDescription: new FormControl(''),
      questions: new FormArray([
        this.initQuestion()
        ])
    });
  }
  initQuestion() {
    return new FormGroup({
      questionTitle: new FormControl(''),
      questionType: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      options: new FormArray([
        this.initOptions()
      ])
    });
  }

  initOptions() {
    return new FormGroup({
      optionTitle: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  addSection() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.survey.get('sections');
    control.push(this.initSection());
  }`
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/deep-nested-reactive-form